# How to create a <string-array> with custom items attributes?

Tags: android, xml

I'm a JS developer and thinking as HTML when I want to implement a select I simply do this:

```
<select name"cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

With JS is too easy to manipulate the view.

When I'm trying to implement in android XML:

```
<string-array name="cars">
    <item value="volvo">Volvo</item>
    <item value="saab">Saab</item>
    ...
</string-array>
```

Android XML doesn't has a value attribute and seems cannot add new attributes to a  tag.

How to translate it to android XML Spinner with both **value** and **text** and link into the Java code to **get a selected item value** in a simple way in XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way of holding values and items like you are trying to achieve. What you can do is to define two separate arrays and reference one another in code by the same index:

```
<string-array name="cars">
    <item>Volvo</item>
    <item>Saab</item>
</string-array>
```

and

```
<string-array name="cars_values">
    <item>volvo</item>
    <item>saab</item>
</string-array>
```

Retrieve the arrays and now the same index in different arrays hold both the value and the actual car:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] cars = res.getStringArray(R.array.cars);
String[] carsValues = res.getStringArray(R.array.carsValues);
```

AS you're using this in a spinner you can get the selected position by calling:

```
int pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

and access the values like:

```
String selectedItem = cars[pos];
String selectedValue = carsValues[pos];
```

Comment: Ok, I should declare the values in all strings files for all languages? Is there a way to define once?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here :/ Once you've declared that above array you'd be able to use it as many times as you want.

Comment: ok, for me is a little bit uggly as a JS + HTML dev, but if is the unique way to do this, it's ok!
Thanks @Levi!